# How to delete attachment using refile ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refile

I'm trying to delete / destroy an attachment I have uploaded using the refile gem, and I'm currently getting the following error, 
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ImagesController#destroy`

`Couldn't find Image with 'id'=`

**images_controller.rb**

```
def destroy
        # binding.pry
        @image = Image.find(params[:id])
        @image.destroy
        flash[:notice] = 'deleted'
        render 'new'
    end

    private

    def image_params
        params.require(:image).permit(:tshirt_image, :remove_tshirt_image)
    end
```

And the form / view in which I'm trying to delete the attachment looks like,

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1>show.html.erb</h1>

<% debug(@image) %>

<%= image_tag attachment_url(@image, :tshirt_image, :fill, 300, 300, format: "jpg") %>

<%= form_for @image do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :tshirt_image %>
  <% form.attachment_field :tshirt_image %>

  <%= form.check_box :remove_tshirt_image %>
  <%= form.label :remove_tshirt_image %>

  <%= button_to "delete", @image, method: :delete %>


<% end %>

<p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code correctly, all of your form's params will be nested under the `:image` key (`params[:image][:remove_tshirt_image]`, etc).

Try:

`@image = Image.find(params[:image][:id])`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately it yields the same error message.